# how to remove TabBarView invisble padding?

Tags: flutter, dart

how to remove TabBarView invisble padding? I put 2 button in the but the 2 edge of my button seem to be cut off a few pixels. how do I fix it?

```
DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        initialIndex: _setInitialTab(context),
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: TabBar(
            // labelPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
            // indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
            labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
            indicatorColor: AppSetting.buttonColor1,
            unselectedLabelColor: AppSetting.buttonDisabledColor1,
            indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
            indicatorWeight: 2,
            tabs: <Tab>[
              Tab(text: "Popular"),
              Tab(text: "New"),
            ],
            onTap: (value) {
            },
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            children: [
              _tab(context, Tab.Popular),
              _tab(context, Tab.New),
            ],
          )
        )
      )
```

[image]

Comment: You can try `Tab(child: PreferredSize(child: Text("Popular"), preferredSize: null)),` insted of your Tab.

Comment: hmm...doesnt help.